# Save Audit Sp in a proper format

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, audit-logging

I'm using a database trigger to save the stored procedure code after an alter.
I get the code using the EventData info.
My problem is that it's saving the code as plain text, so it's difficult to compare the code against other version of the procedure (all the code is in the same line).
Is there a way to save the code in a redeable format?
Thanks,
Andres

Answer (score 1):

This may seem blatantly obvious and silly, but it is probably the best answer: Save both the old and the new text for the procedure. They should both be in the same format, and comparing them should be relatively easy.